# what is gendep?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

what is gendep? it builds dependencies, how? any good book to read about this entire gnu make gamut?

Comment: A misspelling of gender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert by any means, but it appears to look at the system calls to open() that a particular binary makes and looks to see if the opened file matches a particular regular expression.  If it finds a match, it records this match in a file GNU make can parse.

http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~lester/gendep/index.html

As far as GNU make, I know there's an O'Reilly book out there on the subject but this free tutorial does a good job going over the basics: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html